# TypeScript/Angular2: rxjs errors TS1138, TS1005, TS1128

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm following an Angular 2 tutorial, and when I run `gulp dev` I get these errors in the terminal. I'm using Typescript 2.0.3:

```
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(8,38): Error TS1138: Parameter declaration expected.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(8,42): Error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(8,57): Error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(8,58): Error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(8,70): Error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(9,38): Error TS1138: Parameter declaration expected.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(9,42): Error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(9,57): Error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(9,70): Error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(9,86): Error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(9,87): Error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(9,99): Error TS1005: '(' expected.
```

And in the browser the angular app doesn't load. Can someone explain what is going on?

EDIT: These are lines 8 and 9 from `node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts`

```
export declare function toPromise<T>(this: Observable<T>): Promise<T>;
export declare function toPromise<T>(this: Observable<T>, PromiseCtor: typeof Promise): Promise<T>;
```

And this is the only file that uses the `toPromise` method:

**weather.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";

interface WeatherApiResponse {
    query: {
        count: number;
        created: string;
        lang: string;
        results: {
            channel: {
                item: {
                    condition: {
                        code: string;
                        temp: string
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

export interface WeatherInformation {
    city: string;
    code: number;
    temperature: number;
}

export interface City {
    name: string;
    imageSrc: string;
    woeId: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {
    cities = [
        {name: "Bogota", imageSrc: "img/bogota.jpg", woeId: "368148"}
    ];

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getWeather(woeId: string) {
        const url = this.generateWeatherUrl(woeId);
        return this.http.get(url).toPromise()
            .then(x => {
                const apiResponse = x.json() as WeatherApiResponse;
                const weather = apiResponse.query.results.channel.item.condition;
                return {
                    city: this.getCityName(woeId),
                    code: Number(weather.code),
                    temperature: Number(weather.temp)
                } as WeatherInformation;
            });
    }

    private generateWeatherUrl(woeId: string) {
        return `http://localhost:8001/api/weather/${woeId}`;
    }

    private getCityName(woeId: string) {
        const matches = this.cities.filter(x => x.woeId === woeId);
        return matches.length === 1 ? matches[0].name : undefined;
    }
}
```

This is the function that calls the `getWeather()` method in `weather.service.ts`

**weather.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        const woeId = params["woeId"];
        this.weatherService.getWeather(woeId)
            .then(x => this.weather = x);
    });
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which version of `rxjs`? What do lines 8 and 9 of that file look like? How are you using Typescript? (info about your build steps; even though `Typescript 2.0.3` is available, is it being used?)

Comment: I am using rxjs 5 beta and I typed in `npm install
bower install
typings install`, then when I save a .ts file Visual Studio Code converts it into a companion .js file. Lines 8 and 9 are now laid out in my question.

Comment: specifically ^5.0.0-beta.12

Comment: @LesPaul Can you show how you compile this with TypeScript?

Comment: VSCode automatically compiles the .ts files to .js files on save

Comment: I included the tsconfig.json file if that helps at all

Comment: @LesPaul I guess you are doing the Angular 2 projects book... I have the same issue. Normaly the `gulp dev` task transpiles all `.ts` files in `.js` in a `dist` folder. But nevertheless I get the issue. Could you figure out what it is exactly?

Comment: @Samuel Honestly, I just rebuilt the application and took all the useful code (components, directives, etc.) and integrated it into the Angular 2 Quickstart application provided by the Angular 2 team. It started to work there, albeit with other issues regarding Angular 2 Projects using older versions of Angular 2 - keep that in mind.

Comment: I notice a trend with Packt publishing products: code written by people who are skilled at coding, but cannot effectively teach how or why it works and don't provide effective tools to help the user troubleshoot if the application doesn't work. As a former-teacher-transitioning-into-programming it frustrates me how bad some programmers are at instruction.

Comment: @Samuel I should mention I relied on systemjs.config.js from the angular 2 quickstart files to get it working and i didn't use gulpfile.js. I've never used Gulp so this was just an easier option for me

Comment: @LesPaul Thank you. What is weird is that I use gulp and my files are transpiled, but I get the same issue as you. It was only the components/services files that you needed to transpile right? or some other ones I did not think about.

Comment: @Samuel I transpiled all my .ts files, I think that is the correct practice, but without seeing your files I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

For those following Packt *Angular 2 Projects* by Levi Botelho with the proposed **gulp** configuration and who have the same issue for the weather app you can solve it by updating your dependencies ( @angular ).

it works with the following dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12"
  }
```

Checkout the gulp.js file as the one in the video is not the same as the one in the code you can download...

```
const argv = require("yargs").argv;
const browserify = require("browserify");
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
const buffer = require("vinyl-buffer");
const cache = require("gulp-cached");
const concat = require("gulp-concat");
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const gulp = require("gulp");
const gulpIf = require("gulp-if");
const htmlmin = require("gulp-htmlmin");
const inject = require("gulp-inject");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const source = require("vinyl-source-stream");
const sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
const tsify = require("tsify");
const tslint = require("gulp-tslint");
const uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
const watchify = require("watchify");

const rootBuildPath = "./dist/";
const cssBundleName = "site.css";
const cssBundleBuildPath = rootBuildPath + "/css/" + cssBundleName;
const cssSource = "./scss/site.scss";
const cssBuildPath = rootBuildPath + "css";
const fontSource = "./bower_components/weather-icons/font/**";
const fontBuildPath = rootBuildPath + "font";
const htmlSource = "./index.html";
const imgSource = "./img/*.jpg";
const imgBuildPath = "./dist/img";
const jsBundleName = "bundle.js";
const jsBundleBuildDirectory = rootBuildPath + "app";
const jsBundleBuildPath = jsBundleBuildDirectory + "/bundle.js";
const jsSourceDirectory = "./app";
const jsEntryPoint = jsSourceDirectory + "/main.ts";
const jsSource = jsSourceDirectory + "/**/*.ts";
const libSource = [
    "node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js",
    "node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.map",
    "node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js",
    "node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js",
    "node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js.map",
];
const libBuildPath = rootBuildPath + "/lib";
const serverSource = "./server.js";
const templatesSource = "./app/**/*.html";
const templatesBuildPath = rootBuildPath + "app";
const typings = "./typings/index.d.ts";

function logError(err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    this.emit("end");
}

function shouldMinify() {
    return argv.release;
}

gulp.task("lint", function () {
    gulp.src(jsSource)
        .pipe(tslint({
            formatter: "verbose"
        }))
        .pipe(tslint.report())
        .on("error", logError);
});

var browserifyOptions = {
    debug: !shouldMinify(),
    entries: [jsEntryPoint, typings],
    plugin: [tsify]
};

if (argv.watch) {
    browserifyOptions.cache = {};
    browserifyOptions.packageCache = {};
    browserifyOptions.plugin.push(watchify);
}

var browserifyInstance = browserify(browserifyOptions);

gulp.task("js", ["lint"], function () {
    return browserifyInstance
        .bundle()
        .on("error", logError)
        .pipe(source(jsBundleName))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(gulpIf(shouldMinify(), uglify().on("error", logError)))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsBundleBuildDirectory));
});

gulp.task("css", function () {
    return gulp.src(cssSource)
        .pipe(concat(cssBundleName))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: shouldMinify() ? "compressed" : "nested"}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssBuildPath))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task("font", function () {
    return gulp.src(fontSource)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(fontBuildPath));
})

gulp.task("img", function () {
    return gulp.src(imgSource)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(imgBuildPath));
});

gulp.task("lib", function () {
    return gulp.src(libSource)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(libBuildPath));
});

gulp.task("templates", function () {
    return gulp.src(templatesSource)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(templatesBuildPath));
});

gulp.task("html", ["js", "css"], function () {
    return gulp.src(htmlSource)
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src([jsBundleBuildPath, cssBundleBuildPath], {read: false}), {ignorePath: "dist"}))
        .pipe(gulpIf(shouldMinify(), htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true})))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(rootBuildPath));
});

gulp.task("server", function () {
    return gulp.src(serverSource)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(rootBuildPath));
})

gulp.task("default", ["font", "html", "img", "lib", "templates", "server"]);

gulp.task("html-watch", ["html"], () => browserSync.reload());
gulp.task("js-watch", ["js"], () => browserSync.reload());
gulp.task("templates-watch", ["templates"], () => browserSync.reload());

gulp.task("dev", ["default"], function () {
    exec("node dist/server", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.error(stderr);
    });

    gulp.watch(htmlSource, ["html-watch"]);
    gulp.watch(jsSource, ["js-watch"]);
    gulp.watch(templatesSource, ["templates-watch"]);
    gulp.watch(cssSource, ["css"]);

    browserSync.init({
        port: 8001,
        proxy: "http://localhost:3011"
    });
});
```

If you have other issues, download the code as well as the component/services are not really like in the videos.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to transpile .ts into .js and I had assumed Visual Studio Code automatically did this for me. For those who are having the same problem, go to [this site](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_step-2-create-tasksjson) and follow step 2.

> ### Step 2: Create tasks.json
>
> The next step is to set up the task configuration. To do this open the
>   Command Palette with ⇧⌘P and type in Configure Task Runner, press
>   Enter to select it. ...
>
> Select TypeScript - tsconfig.json. This will create a `tasks.json` file
>   in the workspace `.vscode` folder.
>
> The content of the tasks.json file looks like this:
>
> ```
> {
>   // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
>   // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
>   "version": "0.1.0",
>   "command": "tsc",
>   "isShellCommand": true,
>   "args": ["-p", "."],
>   "showOutput": "silent",
>   "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
> }
> ```
>
> Under the covers we interpret `tsc` as an external task runner
>   exposing exactly one task: the compiling of TypeScript files into
>   JavaScript files. The command we run is: `tsc -p .`